# Does the equation have two roots?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the equation
$$-x^2+\sqrt{2-x^2} \left(x^2+2
   x-1\right)+2 x+5=0.$$ 
I tried

```
 NSolve[-x^2 + 2 x + 5 + (x^2 + 2 x - 1) Sqrt[2 - x^2] == 0, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -1.41041}, {x -> -1.}}

When I use *Geogebra*, I got one solution

[image: Geogebra result]

and with *Maple*, I tried
[image: Maple result]

I also got one solution.

Does the above equation have two roots?

**EDIT**
with *Geogebra*, we can see the equation have two roots

[image]

Comment: Why not substitute the two values back in the equation and see if you get zero ?

Comment: In what way is it difficult to check the results?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maple's `fsolve` missed one real root. You can see that by using `solve` with `AllSolutions` options

```
restart;
eq:= -x^2 + 2*x + 5 + (x^2 + 2*x - 1)* sqrt(2 - x^2)=0;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
solve(eq,x,'AllSolutions'):
evalf(%);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
#pick the non-complex roots 
select(type,[%],numeric);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So this is wrong:

```
 fsolve(eq,x,real)
 # -1.000000000
```

And Mathematica is correct:

```
NSolve[-x^2 + 2 x + 5 + (x^2 + 2 x - 1) Sqrt[2 - x^2] == 0, x, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Solve[-x^2 + 2 x + 5 + (x^2 + 2 x - 1) Sqrt[2 - x^2] == 0, x, Reals]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:**

I was reading [Maple's fsolve](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=fsolve) and noticed this:

> For a general equation or system of equations, the fsolve command
>   computes a single real root.

So it looks like it is by design it works like this (finds one root), This is because when I did

```
#check type
type(eq,polynom );
      #  false
```

So Maple's `fsolve` is only meant for polynomials, not general equations, and what you have is not a polynomial, (unless you just want one root, then it is OK to use it). Notice that  [Mathematica 'NSolve'](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveAnEquation.html) says

> If your equations involve only linear functions or polynomials, then
>   you can use NSolve to get numerical approximations to all the
>   solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Just for variety, but as Nasser has illustrated this is dealt with well with well with `Solve` and `NSolve` specifying `Reals` domain (and I have upvoted his answer). You can use root approximations from `Mesh` points of plot of points to inform `FindRoot`. You can find roots of polynomial within domain $\sqrt{2}<r<\sqrt{2}$. The plots are very helpful obviously.

```
f[x_] := -x^2 + 2 x + 5 + (x^2 + 2 x - 1) Sqrt[2 - x^2]
g[x_] := Expand[(2 - x^2) (x^2 + 2 x - 1) ^2 - (x^2 - 2 x - 5)^2]
pl = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -2, 1}, MeshFunctions -> (f@#1 &), 
  Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshStyle -> Red]
rootapp = 
 Union[Extract[pl[[1, 1]], List /@ Cases[pl, Point[x_] :> x, -1]][[1, 
    All, 1]], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 0.001 &)]
FindRoot[g[x] == 0, {x, #}] & /@ {-2, 0}
FindRoot[f[x], {x, #}] & /@ {-1.4, 0}
CountRoots[g[x], x]
```

yields:
[image]